# Probability that $12$ passengers don't get out of the bus for exactly $3$ stops

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

There are $12$ passengers on the route, $10$ stops until the end.
Each of them gets off at any of the stops before the end of the route.
What is the probability, that passengers won't get off exactly at 3 stops?

My solution:

Overall there are $10^{12}$ occurrences.

Passengers won't get off at exactly $3$ different stops. This means that at each remaining stop there will be at least one person that will get off.

We know, that we gonna divide, to get the probability, by $10^{12}$.

Lets pick up these $3$ stations where no passengers will get off, there are $\binom{10}{3}$ ways.

There are $7$ stations left, where passengers can get off;
there are 12 passengers overall.

This means we can distribute $12$ passengers to $7$ stations left,
so there are $7^{12}$ ways.

So the probability is: $$\frac{\binom{10}{3}7^{12}}{10^{12}},$$ which is equal to: $1.66095$, more than one.

The answer is clearly not correct. Where is the mistake?

Comment: The passengers getting off at the "available" $7$ stops aren't free to choose uniformly at random.  You need at least one of them to get off at each of those stops...you haven't taken that into account.

Comment: Moreover, given that your method allows more than $3$ empty stops, you are badly overcounting...since patterns with more than $3$ empty slots are counted multiple times.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thank You for the response, gonna take this into account,
I slightly refactores that part, where I wrote  7^12 , which is wrong indeed.
I refactored that into the number of ways of distributing 12 people into 7 stops that no stops are empty:
7! {7 12} , where {7 12} = 627,396    , stirling number of the second kind.
Now, overall probability fell into ~0.379449

Comment: In how many ways you can put $12$ distinguishable balls in $7$ distinguishable boxes such that neither of box is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, after choosing the three missed stops the passengers' alighting points are still constrained to use each remaining stop at least once, which $7^{12}$ does not account for at all – it allows more stops to be missed entirely and therefore overcounts.

The correct approach is to compute the number of ways the $12$ passengers can get off at the $7$ "hit" stops while "hitting" each at least once – this is $7!S(12,7)$ where $S$ is the [second-kind Stirling number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). This can then be multiplied by $\binom{10}3$ and divided by $10^{12}$ to get the final result of about $0.37945$.

Comment: I just fixed an issue a minute ago, before your post, Thanks tho! :)

Comment: @OlgierdJankovski Remember that you should upvote and accept my answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, Stirling numbers of the second kind is the slick way to make the computation if you have tables at hand, but we can also do it in a more pedestrian way using good old inclusion-exclusion.

Denoting by $S_k = \binom{10}{k}(10-k)^{12}$ that $k$ of the stops have been missed regardless of others,

P(*exactly* $3$ stops missed)

$= \Large{S_3 -\binom41S_4 +\binom52S_5 - \binom63S_6 +\binom74S_7-\binom85S_8 + \binom96S_9 \over10^{12}} \approx 0.37945 $